# Dagger Annotation Processor fails to find com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have been charged with integrating Dagger in our existing project and I am having a bit of a problem with the dagger annotation processor.

My environment is pretty restricted so I cannot just use jcenter() or even Google Maven to get dependencies.  We have an internal Ivy repo that stores and manages all of our Dependencies.

That said, I have pulled down all the dependencies that Dagger requires but I still have an issue.  Gradle sync finishes successfully and resolves the dependencies, however when I go to build I get the following error.

> error: Bad service configuration file, or exception thrown while
>   constructing Processor object: javax.annotation.processing.Processor:
>   Provider dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor could not be
>   instantiated: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   com/google/common/collect/SetMultimap

Clearly I am missing a dependency as when I specifically specify and allow jcenter() and Google Maven as repositories, which I can do for testing purposes, but for prod building this cannot be allowed,  I am able to build with no exceptions.

Now a strict reading of the error tells me that Dagger cannot find com.google.comm.collect.SetMutliMap.

I have searched quite a bit trying to find this dependency and about all I can find is that this file is a part of Guava or at least some of its functions are.

One thing to note is I am using the following version of gradle:

```
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

Here is my dagger dependency in build.gradle which is an older version:

```
    //Dagger
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.10'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10'
```

Other dependencies:

```
    //lifecycle libs
    compile "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.3"
    compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.0.0"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.0.0"

    compile 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.1'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.4'
    compile 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'

    compile 'com.github.ganfra:material-spinner:2.0.0'

    compile 'com.nulab-inc:zxcvbn:1.1.3'

    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:10.2.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }

    compile 'org.zakariya.stickyheaders:stickyheaders:0.7.6'

    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'

    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.2.1') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:26.1.0'

    //retrofit dependencies
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'
```

Due to my restricted environment, I cannot update dependencies as I would like to do, so working within what I have, does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out `com.google.common.collect` is part of `com.google.guava`
With that find in hand I found a solution that works. For whatever reason `dagger-compiler` was not resolving its own dependency, which is `com.google.guava`.

My solution consists of excluding the guava dependency from the compiler and adding it to the annotationProcessor path. I also exclude find bugs for my case as an older version is a dependency in our test project.

```
annotationProcessor ('com.google.guava:guava:22.0'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.code.findbugs'
}
annotationProcessor('com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.13') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
```